# Filter MySQL Table Search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up a PHP MySQL search script which will let me print the content of my membership MySQL database table and then filter the results using different criteria.

The following fields are used in my MySQL table:

committee_id
rank 
last_name 
first_name
sex
address
email
phone_number
active_status

I want 2 ways to filter the data:
1) using using a drop down with all the available rank i can filter the results by rank of member.
2) using a drop down with all the available active_status you can filter the results by active status only.

I have set up my search form successfully, and printed all MySQL Table contents, Only the search by position part is filtering my result, but not the active_status, the filter part is a challenge. here is my html table and search script:

```
   <?php include("./includes/connnect.php");?>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <body>
   <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>position</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Sex</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><strong>Email</td>
            <td><strong>Phone Number</td>
            <td>Status</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php               
            if ($_REQUEST["position"]<>'') {
                $search_position = " AND position='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["position"])."'";   
            }
            if ($_REQUEST["status"]<>'') {
                $search_status = " AND status='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["status"])."'"; 
            }
             else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE committee_id>0".$search_position.$search_status;
            }

            $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
            if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
            ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["committee_id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["rank"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["sex"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["phone_number"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["active_status"]; ?></td>
              </tr>
            <?php
                }
            } else {
            ?>
            <tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
            <?php   
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to get this going.

Thanks.

Comment: `active_status` OR `status` ?! and what is the datatype?

Answer (score 1):

That is because when there is `$_REQUEST["status"]` the variable SQL is not setted as you put it on the else statement

```
if ($_REQUEST["status"]<>'') {
            $search_status = " AND status='" . 
                           mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["status"])."'"; 
        }
         else { /// this is your problem

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." 
                     WHERE committee_id>0".$search_position . $search_status;
        }
```

Put the $sql out of the else and take the else out.

Comment: In addition to Jorge's solution, you should also know that `mysql_` is now deprecated. You should learn more about mysqli and PDO if you are just getting started - it would also make your code a lot easier to read and debug in cases like this.[http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php] , PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php. The advantage of PDO is that it is portable across SQL engines. With both, you need not worry AS much about SQL injection or have to escape each var.

Comment: I agree with you Cerd, I shall have to take note of that!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jorge your solution worked. But I got the same result with these elseif statements:

```
if ($_REQUEST["position"]<>'') {
                $search_position = " AND position='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["position"])."'";   
            }
            if ($_REQUEST["status"]<>'') {
                $search_status = " AND status='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["status"])."'"; 
            }
            if ($_REQUEST["position"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["status"]<>'') {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." 
                    WHERE position = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["position"])."' 
                    AND status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["status"])."'";
            }else if ($_REQUEST["position"]<>'') {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE position = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["position"])."'".$search_city;
            }else if ($_REQUEST["status"]<>'') {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["status"])."'".$search_position; 
            }else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE committee_id>0".$search_position.$search_status;
            }
```

I shall have to convert these to mysqli or pdo as advised.